# How to add an XML File to Current Activity Window in Android

Tags: android

Hi guys in my android application i have used Tabs through out the application.When iam in the Portrait orientation i need to display the Tabs.Whenever iam in the Landscape orientation i need to put a layer just above the TabBar so that the TabBar will be in the background.Here in the Landscape orientation the background TabBar runs ,that is just we have added one layer on top of the TabBar.And also i need to display different layout in the landscape orientation.I have heared about the Window object of the Current Activity that we can add a XML layout to the Window and makes it visible and invisible whenever we require.But i haven't find any code regarding Window.Any Suggestions

Answer (score 0):

You can define different layouts for each orientation. For portrait layouts use the `layout-port` folder, for landscape use `layout-land`. Android will choose the right one depending on the orientation of the device.

See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

Comment: If i use different layouts for portrait and landscape every time the Xml will be loaded.Here i dont want to use two setcontentviews for portrait and landscape.my requirement is i just want to add a layer i.e., in the background the portrait view should runs because i needs to send webservice request from the background.

Comment: In Android is it possible to add a View to Current Activiy Window when iam in the landscape and i want to make it invisible when iam in the Portrait